# How can I set a default value in an inline admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Let's say I have a NarratorAdmin page to display and change details of the Narrator model. It includes a BookInline where the narrator's Books can be changed, added or deleted.
Not all of Book's fields are present in the BookInline-- only the most "important" ones.

Let's further imagine that Book has a "category" field, with values like print, digital, hybrid, audiobook.

When a Book is created from the NarratorAdmin page, I want to automatically set its "category" to "audiobook". "category" is NOT included in BookInline.fields. The user doesn't need to see it and it doesn't make sense for them to change it.

I've tried the following methods (all suggested by AI):

```
def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    formset = super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
    formset.form.base_fields['category'].initial = "audiobook"
    return formset
```

(Doesn't work because "category" is not in base_fields)

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.category = 'audiobook'
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

(After adding some print statements, I don't think this method is actually being called)

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
    for instance in instances:
        instance.category = 'audiobook'
        instance.save()
    formset.save_m2m()
```

Similar to the above, this one doesn't seem to be getting called when I expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to set a default value directly in the model definition ?

```
class Category(models.TextChoices):
    PRINT = "print", "Print"
    AUDIOBOOK = "audiobook", "Audiobook"
category = models.CharField(default=Category.AUDIOBOOK, choices=Category.choices, max_length=10)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is overriding the save in Book.

```py
class Book:
    category = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=BOOK_CATEGORIES)
    narrator = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    # ... lots of info about the book
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.narrator:
            self.category = "audiobook"
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This does have some odd ux implications that aren't ideal: If a user goes to the Book change page and sets the 'category' to be something different, but doesn't remove the narrator link, it will end up an "audiobook" anyway. But that's a completely different problem, which I will solve later...

Comment: You could directly provide the value in the 
category = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=BOOK_CATEGORIES, default = "<<name here>> or if you're using classes for enums just put BOOK_CATEGORIES.<whatever>")

Comment: You could directly provide the value in the 
category = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=BOOK_CATEGORIES, default = "<<name here>> or if you're using classes for enums just put BOOK_CATEGORIES.<whatever>")